# Parse Saving Object with Empty Pointer Column

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Is it possible to save a parse object with an empty column (pointer value)?

In my code, if a user is not logged in, I want to leave "userSubmitted" empty

```
        var sendReport = PFObject(className:"UserReport")
        sendReport["ReportReason"] = reason
        sendReport["ReportedPhoto"] = reportedPhoto
        if PFUser.currentUser() == nil
        {
            sendReport["UserSubmitted"] = nil
            //sendReport["UserSubmitted"] = ""
        } else {
            sendReport["UserSubmitted"] = PFUser.currentUser()
        }
        sendReport.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        [...]
        }
```

Crashes at `sendReport["UserSubmitted"] = nil` and `sendReport["UserSubmitted"] = ""`

```
[Error]: invalid type for key UserSubmitted, expected *_User, but got string (Code: 111, Version: 1.7.2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unset an attribute, use [removeObjectForKey](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/removeObjectForKey:)...

```
sendReport.removeObjectForKey("UserSubmitted")
```